# Surface gravity for a rotating charged black hole

Tags: black-holes, dimensional-analysis, kerr-newman-metric

I have that the surface gravity (at the outer event horizon) for a Kerr-Newman black hole is
$$
K_+ = \frac{r_+-r_-}{2(r_+^2+(J/M)^2)} = \frac{\sqrt{M^2-Q^2-J^2/M^2}}{2M^2-Q^2+2M\sqrt{M^2-Q^2-J^2/M^2}}
$$
where $r_\pm$ are the outer and inner event horizons, $M$ is the mass, $Q$ is the charge, and $J$ is the angular momentum.

I have a simple question, almost too dumb to ask: what (natural) units are used here, such that $M$, $Q$, $r_\pm$, and $J/M$ are dimensionally equivalent?

Comment: See [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr-Newman_metric#Mathematical_form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Planck units $\hbar=G_N=c(=k_B)=1$ see f.e. http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Bekenstein-Hawking_entropy equation (11) where $T=\kappa/(2 \pi)$ (in Planck units)

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I was looking for! (I'll upvote as soon as I can -- not able to right now.)